# How to create a Flutter Stream using MongoDB (watch collection?) with Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying out **MongoDB as database for my Flutter project** lately, since I want to migrate from pure Firebase database (some limitations in Firebase are an issue for my project, like the "in-array" limit of 10 for queries).

**I already made some CRUD operations methods in some Firebase Cloud Functions, using MongoDB**. I'm now able to save data and display it as a Future in a Flutter App (a simple ListView of Users in a FutureBuilder).

My question is : **how would it be possible to create a StreamBuilder thanks to MongoDB and Firebase Cloud Functions** ? I saw some stuff about **watch collection** and **Stream change** but nothing clear enough for me (usually I read a lot of examples or tutorial to understand).

Maybe some of you would have some clues or maybe tutorial that I can read/watch **to learn a little bit more about that subject** ?

For now, I have this as an example (NodeJS Cloud Function stored in Firebase), which obviously produces a Future in my Future app (not realtime) :

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://....";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
    await client.connect();
    var results = await client.db("myDB").collection("user").find({}).toArray();
    await client.close();
    return results;
});
```

What would you advice me to obtain a Stream instead of a Future, using maybe **watch collection** and Stream change from MongoDB, providing example if possible !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions are meant for short-lived operations, not for long-term listeners. It is not possible to create long-lived connections from Cloud Functions, neither to other services (such as you're trying to do to MongoDB here) nor from Cloud Functions back to the calling client.

Also see:

- [If I implement onSnapshot real-time listener to Firestore in Cloud Function will it cost more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310444/if-i-implement-onsnapshot-real-time-listener-to-firestore-in-cloud-function-will)
- [Can a Firestore query listener "listen" to a cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579524/can-a-firestore-query-listener-listen-to-a-cloud-function)
- the documentation on [EventArc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/overview), which is the platform that allows you build custom triggers. It'll be (a lot* more. involved though.

Comment: Would you advise me to look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mongodb_realm otherwise ? I thought it was a better option to handle watch from backend, but if it is not possible, maybe the client could handle it ? Have you ever tried this package ?

Comment: You may well be able to handle monitoring of MongoDB from your own backend server, but not from Cloud Functions. I usually listen to updates to Cloud Firestore or the Firebase's Realtime Database directly from within my apps.

Comment: Oh ok thanks ! Just for information if someone is reading this, I tried another package called mongo_dart (https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart). At first I thought it was only handly simple CRUD operations, but as I was reading more closely it is in fact offering the command "watch" which is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing is that it's the client which handle the stream and connection to database, not sure if it is or not a good practice... (I'm a newbie in mobile dev)